# Angular JS : Does $scope exist without controller

Tags: angularjs-scope

I have couple of questions in Angular. Since I am new to angular can you please explain below questions

1. What will be the scope of variable `fname` on below code if we haven't created a controller

   ```
   <html>
   <!-- Included Angular JS -->
   <body ng-app="">
       <input type="text" ng-model="fname" />
       <span ng-bind="fname"></span>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   As per my understanding `$scope` is needed for two-way binding. In the above scenario does `$scope` exist or not, as controller is not created. 
   If it is using `$rootScope` can we able to add a function to alert or console `fname` value

   ```
   <button ng-click="alertme()">Button</button>
   ```
2. Where exactly we use expression inside angular bultin directive. I have seen serveral examples in some cases `{{}}` is used inside builtin directive. E.g: `ng-form="{{}}"` 
   Is there any rule where to expression in directives

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are attached to the DOM as $scope data property, and can be retrieved for debugging purposes

The location where the root scope is attached to the DOM is defined by the location of ng-app directive.

Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope for more details.

Scopes allows two-way data binding, but you can restrict it to one-way.

Regarding **{{}}**

Consider it as a javascript **eval()** function, when you want to evaluate any expression, you should use {{}}. It evaluates the expression and then inserts it in the html.